# how to fix error 404 in angular 7 even tho the URL is correct

Tags: angular, http, web

I am trying to send a post request to my java Rest server and it works fine with 10 URLs but now for some reason, I am getting error 404 on a URL that I provided and I checked it out in Fiddler and it works fine.
my goal is to be able to send my JSON object to my server but I keep getting error 404 for some reason.

This is the Service with the URLs that dont work :

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Coupon } from '../Entities/coupon';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompanyService {

  private CrtCouponURL = 'http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/company/CrtCoupon'
  private RmvCouponURL ='http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/company/RmvCoupon'
  private UpdtCouponURL ='http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/company/UpdtCoupon'
  private GetAllCouponURL ='http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/company/GetAllCoupons'
  private couponByTypeURL ='http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/company/TypeCouponsGet'
  constructor(private http:HttpClient){ }

public createCoupon(coupon:Coupon):Observable<Coupon>{
  return this.http.post<Coupon>(this.CrtCouponURL, coupon ,{withCredentials:true})
}
public deleteCoupon(id:number):Observable<Coupon>{
  return this.http.delete<Coupon>(this.RmvCouponURL+'/?id='+id,{withCredentials:true})
}
public updateCoupon(coupon:Coupon):Observable<Coupon>{
  return this.http.put<Coupon>(this.UpdtCouponURL,coupon,{withCredentials:true})
}
public getAllCoupons():Observable<Coupon[]>{
  return this.http.get<Coupon[]>(this.GetAllCouponURL,{withCredentials:true})
}
public getAllCouponsByType(type:string):Observable<Coupon[]>{
  return this.http.get<Coupon[]>(this.couponByTypeURL+'/?type='+type,{withCredentials:true})
}
}
```

This is a service with URLs that do work:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminService {
  private companyUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/admin/company'
  private customerUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/admin/customer'
  private companyCrtUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/admin/companyCrt'
  private updateCompURL = 'http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/admin/UpdateComp'
  private customerCrtUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/admin/CreateCustomer'
  private customerDelUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/admin/RmvCustomer'
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public createCompany(company: Company): Observable<Company> {
    return this.http.post<Company>(this.companyCrtUrl, company, { withCredentials: true })
  }
  public deleteCompany(id: number): Observable<Company> {
    return this.http.delete<Company>("http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/admin/mycompany/" + id, { withCredentials: true })
  }
  public updateCompany(id: number, company: Company): Observable<Company> {
    company.id = id;
    return this.http.put<Company>(this.updateCompURL, company, { withCredentials: true })
  }
  public getCompany(id: number): Observable<Company> {
    return this.http.get<Company>(this.companyUrl + "?=id" + id, { withCredentials: true })
  }
  public getAllCompanies(): Observable<Company[]> {
    return this.http.get<Company[]>(this.companyUrl, { withCredentials: true })
  }
  public createCustomer(customer: Customer): Observable<Customer> {
    return this.http.post<Customer>(this.customerCrtUrl, customer, { withCredentials: true })
  }
  public deleteCustomer(id: number): Observable<Customer> {
    return this.http.delete<Customer>(this.customerDelUrl + '?id=' + id, { withCredentials: true })
  }
  public updateCustomer(id: number,customer: Customer): Observable<Customer> {
    return this.http.put<Customer>('http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/admin/UpdtCustomer', customer, { withCredentials: true })
  }
  public getAllCustomer(): Observable<Customer[]> {
    return this.http.get<Customer[]>(this.customerUrl, { withCredentials: true })
  }
}
```

few points : 
I am not using SQL for my database.
I dont use: InMemoryDataService.

UPDATE : it dosnt work with Postman either.

The back end code:

```
@Path("company")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CompanyService {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest requst;

    @POST
    @Path(" couponCrt")
    public Response createCoupon(Coupon coupon) {
        HttpSession session = requst.getSession(false);
        CompanyFacade companyFacade = (CompanyFacade) session.getAttribute("companyFacade");
        try {
            companyFacade.createCoupon(coupon);
            return Response.status(Status.CREATED).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CouponSystemWebExeption("Error while creating Coupon : " + coupon.getTitle());
        }
    }
```

Comment: which of those results in 404?

Comment: private CrtCouponURL = 'http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/company/CrtCoupon'
  private RmvCouponURL ='http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/company/RmvCoupon'
  private UpdtCouponURL ='http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/company/UpdtCoupon'
  private GetAllCouponURL ='http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/company/GetAllCoupons'
  private couponByTypeURL ='http://localhost:8080/CouponSystemWeb/rest/company/TypeCouponsGet'

Comment: Can you provide your backend code and header you pass for authentication?

Comment: i provided the backend.

Comment: can you please check typo as I found  @Path(" couponCrt") and in url it is CrtCoupon

Comment: @NirajOza i tried to this still getting error 404

Comment: Final solution you need to do two checks: 1) to check application/json content type in header and 2) inspect your network call in chrome in dev tool to find exact error and what are the parameters passed in request

Answer (score 1):

For your post or put requests you need to first convert it to json string like below

```
public createCustomer(customer: Customer): Observable<Customer> {
let body = JSON.stringify(customer);
    return this.http.post<Customer>(this.customerCrtUrl, body, { withCredentials: true })
  }
```

and for 404 error can you open any get url in browser to check is it working normally or not?

Comment: i check the URL in postman/fiddler as i need to make post requests through that URL. and they work normaly